# Asc(Chr(254)) returns 116 in .Net 1.1 when language is Hungarian

Tags: vb.net, unicode, globalization

I set the culture to Hungarian language, and Chr() seems to be broken.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = "hu-US"
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = "hu-US"

Chr(254)
```

This returns "ţ"  when it should be "þ"

However, `Asc("ţ")` returns 116.

This: `Asc(Chr(254))` returns 116.

Why would Asc() and Chr() be different?

I checked and the 'wide' functions do work correctly:  ascw(chrw(254)) = 254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that your Windows tries to represent Chr(254)="ţ" as a combined letter, where the first letter is Chr(116)="t" and the second ("¸" or something like that) cannot be returned because Chr() only returns one letter.

Unicode text should not be handled character-by-character.

Comment: Sounds probable. We'll really only know by looking at 'hu-US'' Codepage.

Comment: This BLog explains exactly what you are saying.

"Best Fit in WideCharToMultiByte and System.Text.Encoding Should be Avoided"  
http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnste/archive/2006/01/19/515047.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`Chr(254)` interprets the argument in a system dependent way, by looking at the `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage` property. See the [MSDN article about `Chr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46.aspx). You can check whether that value is what you expect. "hu-US" (the hungarian locale as used in the US) might do something strange there.

As a side-note, `Asc()` has no promise about the used codepage in [its current documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc.aspx) (it was there until 3.0).

Generally I would stick to the unicode variants (ending on -W) if at all possible or use the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class to explicitly specify the conversions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to set the code page for the current thread -- the current culture shouldn't have any effect on `Asc` and `Chr`.

Both the [`Chr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46(VS.71).aspx) docs and the [`Asc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc(VS.71).aspx) docs have this line:

> The returned character depends on the code page for the current thread, which is contained in the `ANSICodePage` property of the `TextInfo` class. `TextInfo.ANSICodePage` can be obtained by specifying `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage`.

Comment: Interestingly, the assertion vanishes on the Asc() page when you move to the 3.5 Framework. The mind boggles.

Comment: I am working with legacy code that I cannot modify, so it sounds like changing the current Code Page is the direction that I need to go.  I know how to set CultureInfo and RegionInfo, but not how to set the current thread's Code Page.  

Can anyone show me how to do this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen several problems in VBA on the Mac where characters over 127 and some control characters are not treated properly.
This includes paragraph marks (especially in text copied from the internet or scanned), "¥", and "Ω".

They cannot always be searched for, cannot be used in file names - though they could in the past, and when tested, come up as another ascii number. I have had to write algorithms to change these when files open, as they often look like they are the right character, but then crash some of my macros when they act strangely. The character will look and act right when I save the file, but may be changed when it is reopened.

I will eventually try to switch to unicode, but I am not sure if that will help this issue.

This may not be the issue that you are observing, but I would not rule out isolated problems with certain characters like this. I have sent notes to MS about this in the past but have received no joy.

If you cannot find another solution and the character looks correct when you type it in, then I recommend using a macro snippet like the one below, which I run when updating tables. You of course have to setup theRange as the area you are looking at. A whole file can take a while.

```
        For aChar = 1 To theRange.Characters.count
            theRange.Characters(aChar).Select
            If Asc(Selection.Text) = 95 And Selection.Text <> "_" Then Selection.TypeText "Ω"
        Next aChar
```